# Excel 2013-VBA runtime error 9 inside an UDF containing Advancedfilter statement but it's OK with debugging mode

Tags: vba, excel, udf, advanced-filter

I do not understand why my UDF using AdvanceFilter works in debugging mode (F8) but provided with Error 9 - Subscript out of range when executed in normal mode. As if too rapid in execution (??) on runtime mode, not step by step.

Code sample of my UDF for more precision (gAitemCT is a user defined type) :

```
Public Function fG_PasteCTLinesOnSheetTmpFilteredDataset( _
  ByRef gL_CTLine_P As gAitemCT, ByRef intNbOcc As Integer) As String

 Dim sRet As String, sMsg As String
 Dim iLoop As Integer
 Dim iNbColMax As Integer
 Dim lNbRowMax As Long
 Dim sColWidth As Variant
 Dim rngInput As Range, rngOutput As Range
 Dim rngCriteria1 As Range
 Dim varTmp As Variant
 Dim iArrDime As Integer

 sRet = "OK"
 iLoop = 0

 On Error GoTo Diso

 '>> Constituer le Carré de datas <<
 Worksheets(G_sNameSRCPO).Select
 With Worksheets(G_sNameSRCPO)
   '>>
   lNbRowMax = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
   iNbColMax = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   '>>
 End With

 Worksheets(G_sNameSRCPO).Select
 '>> Defining INput range <<
  Set rngInput  = Worksheets(G_sNameSRCPO).Range("A1").Resize(lNbRowMax,iNbColMax)
  varTmp = salesWksheet.Range(Cells(1, 1)).Value

 '> Copy Header <
 '>> Setting up Criteria range(s) <<
  varTmp = Worksheets(G_sNameSRCPO).Cells(1, 1).Value

  Worksheets(G_sNameReferenceS).Select
  Worksheets(G_sNameReferenceS).Cells(1, 2).Select
  Worksheets(G_sNameReferenceS).Cells(1, 2).Value = varTmp

  ThisWorkbook.Save
  '**
  If (gL_CTLine_P.GsfPO <> 0) Then
  '>>
  'curWBook.Sheets("dataReferences").Activate
   Worksheets(G_sNameReferenceS).Cells(2, 2).Select
   Worksheets(G_sNameReferenceS).Cells(2, 2).Value = gL_CTLine_P.GsfPO
   Set rngCriteria1 = Worksheets(G_sNameReferenceS).Cells(1, 2).Resize(2, 1)
   '>>
  Else

  End If

  '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  '>> Setting up the OUTput range <<
  Worksheets(G_sNameCTcurrentS).Select
  Set rngOutput = Worksheets(G_sNameCTcurrentS).Range("A1")

   '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  '>> Pasting the Result <<<
  Worksheets(G_sNameSRCPO).Select
  rngInput.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=rngOutput, CriteriaRange:=rngCriteria1
  Worksheets(G_sNameCTcurrentS).Select

Veloma:
   '>>
   Set rngInput = Nothing
   Set rngCriteria1 = Nothing
   Set rngOutput = Nothing
   '>>
    intNbOcc = iArrDime
    '>>
    fG_PasteCTLinesOnSheetTmpFilteredDataset = sRet
    Exit Function
   '**
  Diso:

     Beep
     Beep
     sMsg = "PasteCTLinesOnSheetTmpFilteredDataset-ERR ::" & Err.Number & ":: - " & Err.Description
     Debug.Print sMsg
     sRet = sMsg
     Resume Veloma

  End Function
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Could you comment out your "On error goto DISO" command? Then run it and see which line causes the error.

Comment: Hi,
The lines triggering errors are : 
    
    Worksheets(G_sNameReferenceS).Select
    Worksheets(G_sNameReferenceS).Cells(1, 2).Select
    Worksheets(G_sNameReferenceS).Cells(1, 2).Value = varTmp

These lines copy the title and the value for the filtering but on another sheet, not on the same where AdvancedFilter is applyied.

Comment: I recall that these code operate when debugging mode...
Very disturbing

Comment: What value does G_sNameReferenceS have at that point in execution? Also, is there more than one workbook involved? When not otherwise qualified, Worksheets refers to the Active workbook.

Comment: I got THE solutions. I've removed the .Select statement and the great error was to use Worksheets(...)
I use Thisworkbook.Sheets(...).Cells instead and that was corrected.
I even went back to the use of Public Function in Module.
In fact, no need to manipulate Sheets like in classical macro. I wrote with absolute references between sheets amid current workbook.

Thanks a lot for the exchange to find solutions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't Select from a UDF. There are many things you can't do inside a UDF. A UDF is supposed to act on its parameters and return a result. Any side-effects to the workbook/worksheets/window are not allowed.

Instead of using Select, with use the With/End With construct, or assign the range to a range variable and refer to that.

You'll also have to figure out a different way of updating values that aren't the cell that's got the UDF in it. That's also not allowed in UDFs.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll do another arrangement so. You mean, I must use the Event procedures if I need to manipulate Sheets and workbook, isn't it ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that this UDF is inside module. Perhaps, it's allowed to transfer it as Local procedure assigned in the General part of the Userform nesting the AdvancedFilter function...Or isn't it also forbidden ?

Comment: At least in my understanding, a UDF refers to a function that is used in a cell in a spreadsheet. Functions like SUM(), COUNTA(), etc. are pre-defined functions. If you wrote your own MYSUM() function that could be part of a formula in a cell, that would be a UDF. If that's not how you meant it, I'll take a look again to see if I can find a different problem.

Comment: I see what you mean. 
My supposition is that the fact my function is out of the userform (in Module and it returns OK flag or not depending the state) that uses it and precisely the manipulation of sheets with ;Select statement, so contexts are lost.
I'll make transfer step by step to see what happens. It's probably a side effect, I suppose.

Comment: Hello.
I've transformed the function to a simple local Sub with the same code.
The error handler throws the same error with description : Subscript out of range... That makes me crazy !